# Knowing if the result of a SQL request must be a part of another SQL request result

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Let's suppose I have the following table :

```
Id (int, Primary Key) | Value (varchar)
----------------------+----------------
1                     | toto
2                     | foo
3                     | bar
```

I would like to know if giving two request, the result of the first must be contained in the result of the second *without executing them*.

Some examples :

```
# Obvious example
query_1 = "SELECT * FROM example;"
query_2 = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE id = 1;"
is_sub_part_of(query_2, query_1)  # True

# An example we can't know before executing the two requests
query_1 = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE id < 2;"
query_2 = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE value = 'toto' or value = 'foo';"
is_sub_part_of(query_2, query_1)  # False

# An example we can know before executing the two requests
query_1 = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE id < 2 OR value = 'bar';"
query_2 = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE id < 2 AND value = 'bar';"
is_sub_part_of(query_2, query_1)  # True

# An example about columns
query_1 = "SELECT * FROM example;"
query_2 = "SELECT id FROM example;"
is_sub_part_of(query_2, query_1)  # True
```

Do you know if there's a module in Python that is able to do that, or if it's even possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I don't know of any library that will do this for you. My thoughts:

- Parse the SQL, see [this](http://www.wiggy.net/articles/sqlalchemy-in-reverse/) for example.
- Define which filtering operations can be added to a query that can only result in the same or a narrower result set. "AND x" can always be added, I think, without losing the property of being a subset. "OR x" can not. Anything else you can do to the query? For example "SELECT *", vs "SELECT x", vs "SELECT x, y".

Except for that, I can only say it's an interesting idea. You might get some more input on [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Is this an idea you're researching or is it related to a real-world problem you are solving, like optimizing a DB query? Maybe your question could be updated with information about this, since this is not a common way to optimize queries (unless you're working on the DB engine itself, I guess).

Comment: You're right, I forgot this case. `SELECT id FROM example;` is a *subquery* of `SELECT * FROM example;`. Question editted.

Comment: As you said, it's a real-world problem I am trying to solve. I'm not sure I really can explain the real problem because I'm under a confidentiality clause, and also because to be honest it's equivalent to writing a book :)